# bean 'spring.sleuth.baggage-keys' already defined

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

I'm in the midst of upgrading an app from Spring Boot 1.x to Spring Boot 2.x.  When I attempted to run an existing (and previously working) unit test, I saw the following output:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'spring.sleuth.baggage-keys', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/brave/BraveBaggageConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/TraceBaggageConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

My Gradle project uses the following implementation: `'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-core:2.2.8.RELEASE'`

I tried checking with [the Gradle dependencies task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html) to make sure there were no conflicting versions of spring-cloud-sleuth-core and friends. I also looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60294316/spring-sleuth-baggage-key-not-getting-propagated) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62614289/spring-sleuth-baggage-propagation-not-getting-propagated-working) and they didn't solve my problem.

I need to avoid overriding beans, and I'm currently constrained to Spring Boot 2.4.x for my deploy target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [compatibility matrix](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud#adding-spring-cloud-to-an-existing-spring-boot-application), you should use Spring Cloud 2020.0.x aka Ilford (Sleuth 3.x) with Spring Boot 2.4 (or 2.5).

Sleuth 2.2.8 is Spring Cloud Hoxton, it is not compatible with Boot 2.4.